Why does average_precision_score ignore predictions where y_true = 0?
Consider this example:
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics

y_true = np.array([[1, 1, 1],[0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0]])
y_pred = np.array([[1, 1, 1],[.9, .9, .9],[.8, .8, .8]])

aps = metrics.average_precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro')
roc_auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro')
print(f"average_precision_score = {aps:.1f}, ROC AUC = {roc_auc:.1f}\n")

for threshold in np.arange(.8, 1.01, .1):
    y_pred_copy = y_pred.copy()
    y_pred_copy[y_pred_copy >= threshold] = 1
    y_pred_copy[y_pred_copy < threshold] = 0
    precision = metrics.precision_score(y_true, y_pred_copy, average='micro', zero_division=0)
    recall = metrics.recall_score(y_true, y_pred_copy, average='micro', zero_division=0)
    print(f"At threshold {threshold:.1f}, {precision=:.1f} and {recall=:.1f}")

The output is as follows:
average_precision_score = 1.0, ROC AUC = 1.0

At threshold 0.8, precision=0.3 and recall=1.0
At threshold 0.9, precision=0.5 and recall=1.0
At threshold 1.0, precision=1.0 and recall=1.0

The non-zero values in y_pred after the first row are ignored by average_precision_score and roc_auc_score. But isn't it relevant that there are large non-zero false positives in those cases, as indicated by the output from the threshold loop? Is there a way to account for those?

This is because if the true positives are all 0, precision and recall will be zero as well. ROC AUC is undefined in this case.
You can get the full precision across all samples by setting average='samples'. This will break the ROC AUC though, as it will create a divide by zero case in the two "all-zero" sets.
This explaination is more thoroughly laid out in the docs:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#precision-recall-f-measure-metrics
function call docs:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html#sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score
For each of these rows, we are treating them as an individual set of samples, so if there is only one class (zeros in this case) in the set then the precision and ROC are not interesting. Try playing around with giving different values within the set and you will see the results you are looking for I think.

Thanks - that's helpful. I think another way to look at it is that recall is always 1 in the example above, so the area under the precision-recall or FPR-recall curves will always be 1.

Now that I've played with this a little more, I think I understand it. In the earlier example, recall was 1 at every threshold, so the area-under-curve calculations were always 1. Consider this new example:
y_true = np.array([[1, 1, 1],[0, 0, 0]])
y_pred1 = np.array([[.7, .8, .9],[0, 0, 0]])
y_pred2 = np.array([[.7, .8, .9],[.7, .8, 9]])

With y_pred1, precision is 1 at every threshold, so again the area-under-curve calculations are always 1. But with y_pred2, both recall and precision are affected by the threshold. Therefore the area-under-curve calculations do not return 1 (average_precision_score = .5 and ROC AUC = .4). So in this case the y_pred values corresponding to zeroes in y_true are not ignored.
